# Python CGI script not executing when run through HTML form

Tags: html, ubuntu, python-3.x, cgi

I am trying to experiment with python's cgi module, ad do't want to buy an entire server just to accomplish this task. So I have written my html and python cgi script on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer, but the script will not run. Here is the relevant **HTML** code:

```
<form action = "cgi-bin/Login.py" method="get">

    Username <input type = "text" name = "user"><br>

    Password: <input type = "password" name = "password"><br>

    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"><br>

</form>
```

And the **Python** 3 Code

```
import cgi, cgitb

form = cgi.FieldStorage()



# Get data from fields
Username = form.getvalue('user')
Password  = form.getvalue('password')


print ("Content-type:text/html")
print ()
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print ("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
print ("<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (Username, Password))
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

And lastly the popup that I get when I click the submit button on the webpage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup and configure a web server to serve the cgi scripts.  [Here's](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html) the apache documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try use POST in the form. CGI on python needs POST to works.